# Date Parsing from one format to another format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to change date format  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS ( which is stored in database in string format) to mm/dd/yyyy  for their comparison

```
while(rs.next()) 
    {
        reportBean bean=new reportBean();

        String proj_close_date=rs.getString(3);
        String added_on=rs.getString(4);

        DateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        DateFormat myDateFormat1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

        Date myDate1 = null;    
        Date myDate2 = null;
        Date myDate3 = null;
        Date myDate4 = null;
        Date myDate5 = null;
      try 
        {
          if(proj_close_date==null || proj_close_date.trim().equals(""))
          {
              System.out.println("\n ****** In IF Loop ");
              bean.setCust_code(rs.getString("customer_code"));
              bean.setProject_code(rs.getString("project_code"));
              list.add(bean);
          }
          else
          {
                System.out.println("\n ****** In Else Loop ");
                myDate1 = myDateFormat.parse(proj_close_date);
                myDate2 = myDateFormat.parse(frm_date);
                myDate3 = myDateFormat.parse(to_date);
                myDate5 = myDateFormat1.parse(added_on);                        
                myDate4 = myDateFormat.format(myDate5);

                System.out.println("Project Code ---->"+rs.getString(2));                                           
                System.out.println("Proj_close_date ------>"+myDate1);
                System.out.println("From Date ---->"+myDate2);
                System.out.println("to Date ---->"+myDate3);
                System.out.println("Added_on --->"+myDate4);
                System.out.println("Added_on 1 ie Date 5 ---->"+myDate5);

                if(myDate1.after(myDate2) && myDate1.before(myDate3))  // means --> if(proj_close_date.after(frm_date) && proj_close_date.before(to_date))
                 {                          
                    if(myDate1.after(myDate4))  // means --> if(proj_close_date.after(added_on))
                    {
                        bean.setCust_code(rs.getString("customer_code"));
                        bean.setProject_code(rs.getString("project_code"));
                        list.add(bean);
                    }               
                   else
                   {
                       bean.setCust_code(rs.getString("customer_code"));
                       bean.setProject_code(rs.getString("project_code"));
                       list.add(bean);
                   }  
               }//if    
          }//else

        }//try   
        catch (ParseException e) 
       {
             System.out.println("Invalid Date Parser Exception ");
             e.printStackTrace();
       }


    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();

}
catch(SQLException sex)
{
    sex.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    closeConnection();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is your aim, but couldn't you simply use Date or Calendar for comparison?

Comment: Hmm, this question is almost exactly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723710/parse-error-in-java-program. Maybe you can do you homework together...

Answer (score 2):

You have set myDateFormat1 to `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS"`. I think the first `mm` should be in uppercase.

I recommend you check your format strings with the documentation if [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

A few notes

- [convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) is for Java class names to have each noun capitalised, `reportBean` becomes `ReportBean`
- don't refer to SQL columns by position, always use a name instead `rs.getString("customer_code")` rather than `rs.getString(3)`
- use meaningful variable names, `myDate1` becomes `closeDate`
- practice [debugging your code](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2221711/Debugging-a-Java-Program-with-Eclipse.htm) so you can eliminate `System.out.println()`
- gracefully release resources, `stmt.close()` moves within a finally block
- use a [logging framework](http://logback.qos.ch/), rather than swallowing `Exception`, e.g. `log.error("Invalid Date Parser Exception", e);`

Some specific pointers:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS") // as already noted, mm is the format for minute, MM is the format for month
```

---

```
myDate4 = myDateFormat.format(myDate5); // invalid as you are asigning a String to a Date
```

---

```
if(myDate1.after(myDate4)) // irrelevant as both if & else block execute the same code
```

---

```
rs.close() // not necessary as closed when `Statement` is closed
```

*see [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29)*

Are you sure that your database schema is all `varchar` columns?  I'd recommend that you fixed that if its the case.  Otherwise you can call [`rs.getDate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28java.lang.String%29) instead.